# Trying to create a dynamic menu with a common command function

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I'm trying to dynamically create a RECENT FILES menu from a list, then use a common function to process the selected file.

Windows 7, Python 2.7

I can successfully create the menu, but haven't been able to find a way to pass an indicator to the common function to identify the user's selection. I keep slamming up against Python's pass-by-reference; no matter what I try, the last menu argument value created is passed to the command function.

I've searched extensively, and nothing I've found has helped. (I ALMOST got it working with an 'exec', but I'm doing this processing inside a class and 'exec' doesn't seem to like self. functions)

I don't care what I can get - an index, a file name, ANYTHING I can use to determine which entry has been selected. If I'm completely off track with my approach, PLEASE point me elsewhere. I'm a Python newbie, but a veteran programmer and would truly appreciate constructive guidance/ criticism.

Here's my last attempt, which simply demonstrates my problem. Everything I've tried has the same result - only ever returning the last list iteration:

```
    from Tkinter import *

    def processFile(fileIndex):
        print fileIndex

    file_list = [('01','File01'),('02','File02'),('03','File03')]

    root = Tk()

    menu_bar = Menu(root)

    file_menu   = Menu(menu_bar)
    recent_menu = Menu(file_menu)

    Menu(file_menu)

    for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
        file_display = '%d  %s'  %  (int(file[0]), file[1])  # Just making the menu pretty
        recent_menu.add_command(label=file_display, command=lambda: processFile('%d' % i))

    file_menu.add_cascade(label='Recent Files', menu=recent_menu)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

    root.config(menu=menu_bar)

    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
recent_menu.add_command(label=file_display, command=lambda i=i: processFile(i))
```

If you do not use the i=i, the lambda variable are evaluated at run time, in stead of declaration time. - This is default for lambda functions.